# Probably an easy one - PHP/CodeIgniter 'Undefined Variable'

Tags: php, codeigniter

Morning y'all

This is probably an easy one but I barely got any sleep last night and am struggling to comprehend anything.

I've got a CodeIgniter library I've made called Points.php. Here's the contents of Points:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Points
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->database();
    }

    function getpoints($params)
    {
        echo $userid;
    }

}

/* End of file Points.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/Points.php */ ?>
```

As you can see, I'm building it up slowly and it's being kept simple.

In one of my views, I want it to display the number of 'points' (which for the time being is simply the third segment of the URI). I call it like this:

```
<p>Points: <?php $params['user_id']=$this->uri->segment(3,1); echo $this->points->getpoints($params); ?></p>
```

The warning I get back in the view is this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: userid
>
> Filename: libraries/Points.php

Yes I know it's such a simple problem but I've tried lots of things. Some variations include  echoing in Points.php $params['userid']; etc. But I don't see what I'm doing wrong?

This is my first CodeIgniter class and I've fallen at the first step, haha...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Message: Undefined variable: in View page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487200/message-undefined-variable-in-view-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
function getpoints($params)
{
    return $params['user_id']; // since you're passing the whole array
}
```

Use `return` instead of `echo`, you're already using echo on the other side

Answer (score 0):

Crap didnt read your source code properly, you need to access it as an array not a single variable.

`$params['userid']`