# Message: Undefined variable: in View page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am still new at PHP and the MVC concept.  I have been trying to duplicate the CI News Tutorial(http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html), while using my own database and rewriting the code.

I have been unsuccessful.

Here is my controller:

```
    class Main extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->load->model('structures_model');
}

public function structures()
{
    $this->load->model('structures_model');
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login/');
    } else {
        $data['structures_all'] = $this->structures_model->get_structures();
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/navmain', $data);
        $this->load->view('structures', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is my model (structures_model)

```
<?php
class Structures_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_structures()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('structures');
    return $query->result_array();
}

}
```

And my view:

```
<?php foreach ($structures_all as $structures_info): ?>
<h2>Structures</h2>
<div id="main">
    <?php echo $structures_info['str_name'] ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The error im getting is the common :

```
A PHP Error was encountered<
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: structures_all
Filename: main/structures.php
Line Number: 2
```

I am at a loss. I have looked at all the similar errors people have gotten, but can't figure out why exactly the structure_all array is not being defined.  Shouldn't it get created in the controller function where I set :

```
$data['structures_all'] = $this->structures_model->get_structures();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure there's data in the database to populate the array?

Comment: I ran the query inside phpmyadmin and it returned the desired results.

I addition, the "news" table that I created in the tutorial was working fine, so I know the DB config is correct.

Comment: Why are you loading the model twice? And have you tried to set the variable to an empty array instead of calling the database? Or try to declare and output a simple text variable. So we could narrow down the problem to the view or the model.

Comment: I loaded the model twice on accident.  I was troubleshooting and tried putting it in multiple places to make sure it was loading. I forgot to remove it.  

I will try and set it to an empty array.  I did try if (is_arrary(structure_all)) and found that it was not running what was inside the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to debug this would be to assign `$data['structures_all']` a definite array value, say: `$data['structures_all'] = array('foo' => 'bar');`

Is the `$structures_all` variable available in the view now? If it is available, you know that `$this->structures_model->get_structures();` is returning `null`.

Do you have a table in your database called `structures`?

Are you sure your database connection details are filled out in `config/database.php`?

Do you have php error reporting set to all? There might be hidden messages... call `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the constructor of your controller.

Also try echoing: `$this->db->last_query();` to verify your query is being constructed the same way you tried in phpmyadmin...

Hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: I first tried your suggestion to set my array as '$data['structures_all'] = array('foo' => 'bar');'

Just to be clear, I added it to my controller, "Main" under the public function "structures."  I also temporarily removed the '$data['structures_all'] = $this->structures_model->get_structures();' line. 

I was met with the same error.  This time, however, I received a  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error as well.

Comment: I checked my DB config, and its set to the correct DB, and the table exists.  I am currently connecting to the DB via tank_auth, and it is successfully displaying my user name, so I know the DB config isn't the problem.  I have also quadruple checked to ensure the table name wasn't misspelled.  I also set error_reporting(E_ALL); and did not see any other error messages

Comment: In your last suggestion, regarding verifying my query, it gives me a new error: 'Object of class CI_DB_mysql_driver could not be converted to string'

Comment: Upon further testing, im getting pretty sure it has to do with an incorrectly configured routing file.

Comment: I deleted everything and started from scratch.  Upon doing so, I reset my route.php file in config.  I had previously hotwired it in such a way that I had no idea what was going on, but it worked.  Unfortunately, it caught up to me in regards to the DB.  With default routing, and a rewrite of the above code, I got it working the way it should have.

Comment: Couldn't have guessed that! Glad to hear it's working for you now. Cheers!