# CodeIgniter $data not passed from Controller to View

Tags: php, codeigniter

my controller is not passing `$data` to my view and I don't know why not. I'm reusing code from a previous project which worked fine and I certainly understand the idea of how $data passing is meant to work. But maybe I missed something when copying code over?

I put in the variable `$data['hello']` in there just for testing purposes. As you can see from the output `$hello` isn't even getting through. The `if` fails and the `else` code is run correctly which means the view file itself is being loaded.

Controller:

```
function users() {
    $data['title'] = 'users';
    $data['users'] = $this->main_m->get_users();
    $data['hello'] = 5;
    $this->load->view('users', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php
echo $hello;
if ($users->num_rows != 0) {
    foreach ($users->result() as $user) {
    }
} else {
    echo "No users.";
}
```

Output (abridged):

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Message: Undefined variable: hello
Line Number: 2
A PHP Error was encountered
Message: Undefined variable: users
Line Number: 3
A PHP Error was encountered
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Line Number: 3

No users.
```

Edit: more info on request:
Model:

```
public function get_users($amount = 0, $offset = 0) {
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->order_by('l_name', 'desc');
    if ($amount != 0)
        $this->db->limit($amount, $offset);
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: what is your model function get_users()

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code in your view in the `users.php` view file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Message: Undefined variable: in View page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487200/message-undefined-variable-in-view-page)

Answer (score 0):

I always do like this
change your model to

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

And in view

```
if (count($users)> 0) {
foreach ($users as $user) {
echo $user['name'];
}
} else {
echo "No users.";
}
```

Hope this helps

Regards

iijb

Answer (score 0):

Just write `$data = array();` before you are sending some data into `$data` array.

```
function users() {
$data = array();
$data['title'] = 'users';
$data['users'] = $this->main_m->get_users();
$data['hello'] = 5;
$this->load->view('users', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve your issue with some simple var_dump() checks.

1. Check what's coming out of your model by var_dump()ing $data['users'] - is this an object? What happens when you var_dump() $data['users']->result()?
2. Then, var_dump() $data in your view - does it have all the pieces?

Thing is, even showing us your model function doesn't prove that your getting a real data result. Check that. Your code looks okay at a glance so I don't think that is where the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is something very basic that is wrong. So get out of that controller and do a sanity check. First confirm that your welcome view is working. If it is go to the welcome controller and put this in the index method

```
    $data['here'] = 'we are here' ;
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
```

and then somewhere in the welcome.php view file

```
<?php echo $here ?>
```

You do not need to set this: $data = array();
However some people suggest it because that way even if you dont create any data variables you wont get an error if its in the view call $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);

finally i would suggest looking at this

```
  function users() {
     $data['title'] = 'users';
     $data['users'] = $this->main_m->get_users();
     $data['hello'] = 5;
     $this->load->view('users', $data);
 }
```

lets see you have method called users, returning an object called users, and a view called users -- that could get confusing ! :-)